# How to call nested views in monotouch?

Tags: c#, iphone, model-view-controller, view, xamarin.ios

For example the twitter application you can open one profile and see his tweets then open another profile and go and repeat the same action over and over again, then you can tap on the back button as many times you opened tweets and profiles etc, returning from the same path.

a code example would help me a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for examples of a UINavigationController.  This allows you to push new UIViewControllers into the navigation hierarchy and helps manage popping the view controllers off when you hit the back button (you can do this programatically also).

There are a bunch of [articles on MonoTouch.Info about UINavigationControllers](http://monotouch.info/Search?q=uinavigationcontroller).  I think that would be the best starting point for you.

Comment: that link took me no where ... No entry found for "uinavigationcontroller".

Comment: Ok.  Just tried it again and it worked for me so not sure what is happening there.  You can go to http://monotouch.info directly and enter UINavigationController into the search field.  Otherwise try starting here http://www.shrinkrays.net/articles/monotouch-controllers-by-example/uinavigationcontroller-by-example.aspx